# How do permissions in a GCloud IAM role get implemented in a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, rbac, google-iam

I am running a Kubernetes application on GKE. In the GCP IAM console, I can see several built-in roles, e.g. `Kubernetes Engine Admin`. Each role has an ID and permissions associated with it— for example, `Kubernetes Engine Admin` has ID `roles/container.admin` and ~300 permissions, each something like `container.apiServices.create`.

In the kubernetes cluster, I can run:

```sh
kubectl get clusterrole | grep -v system:  # exclude system roles
```

This returns the following:

```
NAME                                                                   AGE
admin                                                                  35d
cloud-provider                                                         35d
cluster-admin                                                          35d
cluster-autoscaler                                                     35d
edit                                                                   35d
gce:beta:kubelet-certificate-bootstrap                                 35d
gce:beta:kubelet-certificate-rotation                                  35d
gce:cloud-provider                                                     35d
kubelet-api-admin                                                      35d
view                                                                   35d
```

I do not see any roles in this table that reflect the roles in GCP IAM.

That being the case, how are the GCP IAM roles implemented/enforced in a cluster? Does Kubernetes talk to GCP, in addition to using RBAC, when doing permissions checks?

Answer (score 0):

[RBAC](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control) system lets you exercise fine-grained control over how users access the API resources running on your cluster. You can use RBAC to dynamically configure permissions for your cluster's users and define the kinds of resources with which they can interact.

Moreover, GKE also uses [Cloud Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://Cloud%20Identity%20and%20Access%20Management%20(IAM)%20to%20control%20access%20to%20your%20cluster.) to control access to your cluster.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, this does not quite answer my question. As I put it in [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306807/how-do-permissions-in-a-gcloud-iam-role-get-implemented-in-a-kubernetes-cluster/55335624#comment97416816_55335624), how do IAM roles actually get enforced in the cluster? Does RBAC inherit them, as @suren suggested? If so, how?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam#overview) you use Cloud IAM to manage which users and service accounts can access, and perform operations in, your clusters, and optionally, you can use Kubernetes RBAC system to configure cluster- or namespace-level permissions. Also, please take a look at this [Medium post](https://medium.com/uptime-99/making-sense-of-kubernetes-rbac-and-iam-roles-on-gke-914131b01922) which explains in detail the RBAC and IAM roles on GKE.

Answer (score 0):

RBAC inherits permissions from IAM, so be careful with that. If you set a cluster-admin permission, for example, in IAM, you will have no way to give less permissions through RBAC.

If you want to use RBAC, you will need to set the lowest permission for the user (given your use case), and then granularly manage the permissions through RBAC.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I'm wondering, though, is not whether permissions are additive, etc; rather, I'm unclear about _how_ RBAC inherits permissions from IAM. In the question I note that none of the GCP IAM roles appear as RBAC roles. If they're inherited, how? For example, does the `cluster-admin` role that you mentioned map to a role in GCP, perhaps `Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin`? If so, where could I find the mapping?

Comment: Not really. A `Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin` is someone who can create clusters, manage resources, etc. A superviser would have this role. `Kubernetes Engine Admin` is the `cluster-admin` in RBAC terms. You can see all the permissions in each role (for all GCP) under IAM & admin > Roles